# Access Wordpress session from cake PHP site

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, cakephp, authentication

This is quite difficulty for me. Please help.
I've a website created with cake PHP in root domain (say mysite.com) and a blog in a directory called "blog" (mysite.com/blog).
I have a register/login feature in PHP site.
So what I want here is, whenever a member login in the main site using the login form, whenever he open the blog (mysite.com/blog), he shoulb be as logged in as the same user logged in the main PHP site.
In the same way, whenever a new user sign-up with the registration form in the main PHP site, he should become an user in the wordpress blog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main site, you have to include WP's functions by using [wp_signon](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); //this disables the theme
require('/blog/wp-blog-header.php'); //includes wordpress functions
```

And then, you can auto-login a user in WP by using

```
$credentials = array();
$credentials['user_login'] = 'example';
$credentials['user_password'] = 'plaintextpw';
$credentials['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
//login failed
echo $user->get_error_message();
}
```

This should work fine, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much Agustin. I put these in my main site's index.php as follows (after including the above two lines):
`$credentials = array();
$credentials['user_login'] = $_SESSION['user']; // john
$credentials['user_password'] = $_SESSION['pwd']; // 1234
$credentials['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
//login failed
echo $user->get_error_message();
}`
But it doesn't works with the wordpress even though there is an user named john with password 1234
What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

To login the user automatically for wordpress, check out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

To create a user take a look at:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user